# Is Evaluation SMS possible in Journey Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobileconnect

I have the following case.

I created a journey and I need to send an SMS as an exit requesting the evaluation of the customer in his experience in the store.
For example: **Hello customer, evaluate our service:
1. Bad.
2. Good.
3. Great.
Please respond with a number from 1 to 3.**

So I want to get the answer and save in a data extension.

Is it possible to do some automation for this?
I'm running out of ideas on how to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the MobileConnect Data Strings and variables.

Get the customer's response using something like:

```
%%[
VAR @response
SET @response= [MSG(0).NOUN(0)] 
UpsertData('DE',1,'Mobile_Phone',MOBILE_NUMBER,'CustomerResponse',"response")
]%%
Thank you for your response...
```

Or you can directly get the customer's `ContactKey` using the `Mobile_Number` and save it to your DE.

The `MSG(0).NOUN(0)` returns the first noun in your customer's message. [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/mobileVariables.htm?search_text=noun)

Comment: Would you mind marking this as answer if it resolved your problem?